# Start working before getting UK Global Talent Visa

Tags: visas, uk

I have been accepted in a research fellow position at a UK university and am in the process of applying for my Global Talent visa. Is it possible to start working remotely in my home country  **before** receiving the visa, then travel to the UK later in the year?

Comment: Have you asked the university? They should have knowledge of what is and isn’t possible

Comment: The HR dept are currently on strike...